# Cannot increase monitor refresh rate on second monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, dvi, refresh-rate

I just purchased an Asus VG248 monitor (supports 144Hz refresh rate) and I can not increase the monitor's refresh rate beyond 60Hz from Windows.

My system setup:

- 2x AMD 6970 graphics cards in Crossfire mode (both flashed to 6990 firmware)
- 1x Asus VG236 connected via DVI cable to graphics card #1 DVI port #1 (120Hz)
- 1x Asus VG248 connected via DVI cable to graphics card #1 DVI port #2 (60Hz)

Does anyone know why I can not set the new monitor to a higher refresh rate of 120Hz (I'm not really looking to get to 144Hz on this new monitor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the website and others mention it needs DisplayPort or dual link DVI for the higher refresh rate.

[ASUS VG248QE](http://www.asus.com/Monitors_Projectors/VG248QE/)

> *To activate 144Hz function (in 2D mode), both DisplayPort (or Dual-link DVI) and a selected graphics card with the latest driver are
>   required. Please kindly contact the service center of your graphics
>   cards companies for further technical supports.

The second DVI port on a 6970 is single link DVI and doesn't support higher resolutions / refresh rates. Easiest option is to use a DisplayPort cable instead of DVI. Specifically a Mini DisplayPort (graphics card end) to DisplayPort (monitor end) cable. Or a DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable and the Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort adapter that likely came with your card.

Comment: My original post was lacking some information (I wrote it at 2AM). The cards are actually 6970's flashed with 6990 firmware. I only want to run the new monitor at 120Hz and not really fussed about 144Hz. There's two DVI ports on each graphics card. Should I switch the new monitor to DVI port#1 on graphics card#2 ?

Comment: With CrossFire enabled the ports on the second card are disabled. The second DVI port on each card is single link only. I would suggest using a DisplayPort cable and connecting to the first card.

Comment: That's rally useful information Brian. Before I order a DisplayPort cable - do I need to get two DisplayPort cables for each monitor? Or, do I just leave the first monitor on the DVI cable and use the DisplayPort one for the new montor? (All running from graphics card#1)

Comment: Can leave the first monitor on Dual-Link DVI then get one DisplayPort cable to use for the second monitor.

Comment: Excellent, I will order the DisplayPort cable now and mark this as answered once I can confirm it worked. Thanks Brian.

Comment: Just got the DisplayPort cable today and plugged it in and was able to set the monitor up to 144Hz. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update your drivers, swap HDMI cables, try connecting to the other port, make sure your power supply is big enough, make sure your cooling mechanism is adequate...

If you just run the VG248 by itself, can you push 144Hz?

Comment: I am using DVI not HDMI. I have the latest AMD Catalyst drivers v13.9/ Power supply is 850W. Cooling system is more than adequate. I will try the VG248 on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Some monitors don't permit 144hz unless you use a DVI-D or dual link port.  You need to check the video card sometime both ports are not DVI-D.  Also if one DVI port is in **dual mode** the other might be **forced** into **single mode**. You might be better off hooking the second monitor to the second video card as both cards are identical and 1 monitor is running at 144hz they have at least 1 DVI-D port each.

Comment: When I plugged my new monitor into the second graphics card no signal was received on the monitor. I should have mentioned that I only want to run the new monitor at 120Hz.